# Price Option B Knowing The Price of a Similar Option A

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility, normal-distribution

How do we find the implied volatility from the price in a call option and apply it to another option without a calculator? Or is there actually a better way?
For example, given a 25-strike 1.0-expiry call option on $S$ has time-0 price 0.90 with $r = 0$, with $S_0 = 20$. Find the price of a 16-strike 1.0-expiry put option on $S$. How do we solve this question mathematically and not numerically?

**Solution:**

I've found the answer for this.

Assuming $r = 0$ and using Black Scholes:
For our 25-strike call option, we know that
$$
20N(d_1^c)-25N(d_2^c) = 0.90, \text{ where } d_{1,2}^c=\frac{\log{20/25}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}=\frac{\log{4/5}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}
$$
Similarly, for our 16 strike put, we know that:
$$
d_{1,2}^p=\frac{\log{20/16}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}=-\frac{\log{4/5}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}
$$
Using this, we can see that $d_{1,2}^p=-d_{2,1}^c$. Hence:
$$
p_{0}=KN(-d_{2}^p)-S_{0}N(-d_{1}^p)=16N(d_1^c)-20N(d_2^c)=7.2
$$

Comment: I understand this is not possible unless it is done computationally but given that this question was asked, it seems like there is a trick somewhere to solve this.

Comment: Is this an exam question? The intent might be to solve it using different methods than back-calculating vol.  E.g. the strikes are nearly symmetrical to the spot price (+/- 20%)

Comment: Yes, it is an exam question with no calculators allowed. I have noticed the symmetry as well but I am unable to get the symmetry to amount to anything. Though I might be missing something.

Comment: So the question is not "how do we find the implied volatility" but "how do we price Option B knowing the price of a similar Option A?" (I do not know the answer but if you frame it that way it might get better responses) (Even if you _did_ know the IV, I doubt you could price the option without a calculator)

Comment: See if https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53662 helps

Comment: Is S the same on Option A and Option B?

Comment: Yes, S at time 0 is the same. I've found the solution and updated the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I've found the answer to this.

Assuming $r = 0$ and using Black Scholes:
For our 25-strike call option, we know that
$$
20N(d_1^c)-25N(d_2^c) = 0.90, \text{ where } d_{1,2}^c=\frac{\log{20/25}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}=\frac{\log{4/5}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}
$$
Similarly, for our 16-strike put, we know that:
$$
d_{1,2}^p=\frac{\log{20/16}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}=-\frac{\log{4/5}}{\sigma}\pm\frac{\sigma}{2}
$$
Using this, we can see that $d_{1,2}^p=-d_{2,1}^c$. Hence:
$$
p_{0}=KN(-d_{2}^p)-S_{0}N(-d_{1}^p)=16N(d_1^c)-20N(d_2^c)=7.2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Kai, I am Kai. Hopefully this answers your question?

A Review on IV Calculations
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042717300602

I don't think there are exact mathematical solutions, but much rather approximates. If you want exact solutions, they should be numerical.

Comment: Thanks, Kai :) But I have to solve this without approximation. It does seem like there is a trick to this.

Comment: @Kai why don't you use put call parity? Actually, I still do not quite understand your question, it is worded quite confusingly.

Comment: I've posted a solution. Hopefully that makes sense. Took me a while to solve it. Thanks for looking at it!